# How to differentiate complex functions like this one?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If
$$
y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2-c^2}}\cos^{-1}{\left(\frac{at-a^2+b^2+ c^2}{t\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right)}
$$
and $t=a+b \cos x+c \sin x$ prove that $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the Chain Rule, which states that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$. Clearly $\frac{dt}{dx} = -b\sin x + c \cos x$. Now, since the derivative of $\cos^{-1} x$ is $-1/\sqrt{x^2 - 1}$, we also have
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2 - c^2}} \cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{(at - a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2}{t^2(b^2+c^2)}}} \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{(at - a^2 + b^2 + c^2)}{t\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right).$$
If the result you claim is true, it's just a matter of basic computation from here.